# How to restrict access if user is not logged in

Tags: jsf, authentication

My project has a template `main.xhtml` and three views `login.xhtml`, `dashboard.xhtml`, `new.xhtml`. Once I login in `login.xhtml`, the `LoginBean` will validate and if successful, then it will take to `dashboard.xhtml`. If user need to create an new record he click the new button which takes to `new.xhtml`.

But the problem is, if `dashboard.xhtml` is requested directly from browser, then it is working without login. Do I need to check every view that the user is logged in? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like as if you're homegrowing authentication. In that case, you need to also homegrow access restriction. That is normally to be done using a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info).

Assuming that you're logging in as follows in a `@RequestScoped` bean,

```
public String login() {
    User user = userService.find(username, password);
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if (user != null) {
        context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("user", user);
        return "dashboard.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    } else {
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Unknown login, try again."));
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you can check for the logged-in user in a `@WebFilter("/*")` filter as follows:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {    
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    User user = (session != null) ? session.getAttribute("user") : null;
    String loginURL = request.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml";

    boolean loginRequest = request.getRequestURI().startsWith(loginURL);
    boolean resourceRequest = request.getRequestURI().startsWith(request.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER);

    if (user != null || loginRequest || resourceRequest)) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect(loginURL);
    }
}
```

Note thus that this would continue the request when the user is logged in, or when the login page itself is requested directly, or when a JSF resource (CSS/JS/image) is been requested.

If you were using container managed authentication, then the filter would have been unnecessary. See also [How to handle authentication/authorization with users in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965708/how-to-handle-authentication-authorization-with-users-in-a-database/)