# JSF f:attribute into a f:event not mapping in backing bean

Tags: jsf, tomcat7

I'am trying to pass a profile name for a webpage (xhtml) to the user bean validator. This is my approoach:

```
<f:event name="verifica" listener="#{RegistroBean.verificaUsuarioLogado}" type="preRenderView">            
        <f:attribute name="perfil" value="profesor"/>
    </f:event>
```

In the backing bean code, the event attributes are empty, but they shouldn't:

```
  public void verificaUsuarioLogado(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
        log.debug("URL " + UtilidadesBean.getRequestURL());
        log.debug("Verificando si está logado");
        if (event.getComponent().getAttributes().isEmpty()) {
            log.debug("No hay nada");
        } else {
            Iterator itr = event.getComponent().getAttributes().entrySet().iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                Entry entrada = (Entry) itr.next();
                System.out.print("Clave " + (String) entrada.getKey() + " Valor " + (String) entrada.getValue());
            }
            String perfil = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("perfil");
            log.debug("Tengo el perfil de la página " + perfil);
        }
        String perfil = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("perfil");
        log.debug("Tengo el perfil de la página " + perfil);
```

Log output:

```
14-abr-2013 12:29:20 DEBUG beans.RegistroBean.verificaUsuarioLogado:231 - URL /spum/generainforme.xhtml
14-abr-2013 12:29:20 DEBUG beans.RegistroBean.verificaUsuarioLogado:232 - Verificando si está logado
14-abr-2013 12:29:20 DEBUG beans.RegistroBean.verificaUsuarioLogado:235 - No hay nada
14-abr-2013 12:29:20 DEBUG beans.RegistroBean.verificaUsuarioLogado:246 - Tengo el perfil de la página null
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<f:attribute>` is only supported in an `UIComponent` parent. The `<f:event>` isn't such one.

Either move the `<f:attribute>` outside the `<f:event>`.

```
<f:event name="verifica" listener="#{RegistroBean.verificaUsuarioLogado}" type="preRenderView" />
<f:attribute name="perfil" value="profesor"/>
```

Or just pass it as method argument in EL, this is new since EL 2.2 which is supported by Tomcat 7.

```
<f:event name="verifica" listener="#{RegistroBean.verificaUsuarioLogado('profesor')}" type="preRenderView" />
```

with

```
public void verificaUsuarioLogado(String perfil) {
    // ...
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, given the method name you seem to want to perform some authentication checks. A JSF view is the wrong place for this. See also [How to handle authentication/authorization with users in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965708/how-to-handle-authentication-authorization-with-users-in-a-database/)

Further, managed bean names must start with lowercase. As you have now is like

```
RegistroBean RegistroBean = new RegistroBean();
```

which is not conform standard [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367). Just omit the `name` attribute from `@ManagedBean`, it'll [default](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanNames) to the right one already.

Comment: Your suggestion solves the problem. About the authentication checks, my authentication works with user/passwords/profiles stored in xml files. I agree with you about it isn't the best place, but it is easy of develop and maintain. I should create a complex servlet filter unsafer... Do you agree?