# jsf 2.0 filter alternative

Tags: security, jsf, filter

since filter only work well when i use page-redirect=true on every commandbuttons' action, i am looking for a usable alternative.

all i have now are two filters (which don't work well):

**Filter A -> /pages/*** (Filter checks if user is logged in)

**Filter B -> /pages/restricted/*** (filter checks if user has admin permissions)

because of the navigation-procedure by JSF they do not work, because the url is never changing.

my question is: **what is the best solution to restict page access without filters** (is there a easy to use security (without complex roles etc.-> some users just have isAdmin=true)? or is there no problem at all when i use redirection? why does jsf then doesn't use it per default?

Is using a prerenderview component an acceptible solution? (if the user dosn't have enough rights, he should be navigated to a 404 page)

Answer (score 1):

You're making a fundamental mistake. You should not be using command (POST) buttons/links for page-to-page navigation in first place, but you should be using direct (GET) buttons/links for that.

Long story short:

- [What is the difference between redirect and navigation/forward and when to use what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277366/what-is-the-difference-between-redirect-and-navigation-forward-and-when-to-use-w)
- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-make-url-reflect-the-current-page-and-not-the-previous-one/)
- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink/)

Considering this information and best practices, a servlet filter is still the best solution. All existing security frameworks are also based on the filter principle.

#### See also:

- [How to handle authentication/authorization with users in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965708/how-to-handle-authentication-authorization-with-users-in-a-database)

Comment: thanks for the help, one thing: can i use a GET button/link (like h:outputlink or h:button) together with a action? i'd like to process the login data by an action which navigates me to the next page (success or fail)

Comment: You should display validation failures in the same page. If login succeeds, just send a redirect to the desired user home page. If you need to show a message along, set a flash message.