# JSF user authorisation

Tags: jsf, authentication, registration

I would like to develop jsf app with user registration and authtorisation. Is it a good idea to manage users via managed bean with boolean property, which identifies if user is logged in. Logging in means checking jpa entity and setting the property to true. Is it secure?

Comment: Your question is vague and not code based...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle authentication/authorization with users in a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965708/how-to-handle-authentication-authorization-with-users-in-a-database)