# WebFilter base on user role

Tags: jsf-2, servlet-filters

Here is my login filter class:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/backend/*", "/frontend/manager/*", "/frontend/faculty/*"})
public class AuthorizationFilter extends HttpFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            HttpSession session, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        UserManagedBean user = session != null ? (UserManagedBean) session.getAttribute("userManagedBean") : null;
        if (user != null && user.isLoggedIn()) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/frontend/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to let the filter class auto filter user to the urlPatterns I configured base on their roles?

For example, if I am an admin so the filter will allow me to access to `/backend/*`. If I am manager, then the filter will allow me to access to `/frontend/manager/*` and disallow me the other ones (backend, faculty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, filters doesn't support role-based URL matching. For that, you should be using Java EE builtin container managed security by `<security-constraint>` entries instead of homebrewed security using a servlet filter. Inside those `<security-constraint>` entries you can declare URL patterns by `<web-resource-collection><url-pattern>` and roles by `<auth-constraint><role-name>`.

Inside a filter, best what you can do is manually checking `HttpServletRequest#isUserInRole()`.

#### See also:

- [How to handle authentication/authorization with users in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965708/how-to-handle-authentication-authorization-with-users-in-a-database)
- [Java EE 6 tutorial - securing web applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html)

Comment: I don't use JDBC realm, so how can I use the `<security-constraint>`?

Comment: As answered, use Java EE builtin container managed security instead of a homegrown filter.