# Null Value for Logged in user using Session Phase Listener and Login Filter j_security_check

Tags: session, jsf-2, servlet-filters, j-security-check, phaselistener

I am using JSF2 and Websphere 8. I have a login filter that authenticates the user using    j_securitycheck. After successful authentication it puts the logged in user in a session.

After this step, Session Management Phase Listener gets executed which checks if the user has requested a protected resource and is a valid user by retrieving the logged userid from the session. I am able to retrieve the session but when i look for **session.getAttribute("userid") it returns null value.**

I have tried with Session Filter instead of Session Management Phase Listener. But no luck. Here is the code snippet. Appreciate your help.

**Login Filter:**

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    //authenticate user
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        if(session!=null){
            if(session.getAttribute("userid") == null){
                session.setAttribute("userid", req.getRemoteUser());
            }
        }

        String currentUser = (String)session.getAttribute("userid");
    System.out.println("Login Filter | Current Logged in user: " + currentUser);

}
```

**sessionManagementPhaseListener:**

```
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    if (event != null) {
        FacesContext facesContext = event.getFacesContext();
        if (facesContext != null) {
            HttpServletRequest origRequest = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext
                    .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
            String requestedUrl = origRequest.getRequestURI();
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext
                    .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                    .getResponse();

            // set the response header here.
            response.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
            response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate");
            response.addHeader("Expires", "Mon, 8 Aug 2006 10:00:00 GMT"); 
            response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);

            if (requestedUrl != null
                    && requestedUrl.contains(PROTECTED_FOLDER)) {


                // HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext
                // .getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
                // HttpSession session = origRequest.getSession();

                Map<String, Object> requestMap = facesContext
                        .getExternalContext().getSessionMap();

                if (requestMap == null) {
                    try {
                        String contextPath = requestedUrl.substring(0,
                                requestedUrl.indexOf(PROTECTED_FOLDER));
                        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                                .getExternalContext()
                                .redirect(contextPath + "login.xhtml");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        gotoLoginPage(response); // go to login page 

                    }
                }

                else {

                    String currentUser = (String) requestMap.get("userid");
                    System.out.println("Current Logged in user: "
                            + currentUser);
                    if (!isLoginPage
                            && (currentUser == null || currentUser == "")) {
                        try {
                            String contextPath = requestedUrl.substring(0,
                                    requestedUrl.indexOf(PROTECTED_FOLDER));
                            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                                    .getExternalContext()
                                    .redirect(contextPath + "login.xhtml");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // go to login page in case of exceptions
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            gotoLoginPage(response);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Neither the filter nor the phase listener are making any sense, certainly when taking into account that you're already using container managed authentication (`j_security_check`). What exactly is it, the problem you're trying to solve with this all?

Comment: Thanks BalusC for the response. I am using the login filter for user authentication but trying to use session phase listener for user session management (Example: if the user is trying to hit the protected URLs (bookmarked) directly without coming through the login page then redirect the user to the login page. Or if the user logged out intentionally but still trying to go to the protected URL to check if the session has been cleared or not.). I am not sure if this is the right way to handle. appreciate any help.

Comment: There you use the `<security-constraint><web-resource-collection><url-pattern>` in `web.xml` for. It looks like you're confusing different approaches of authenticating users. Take a pause and carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965708/how-to-handle-authentication-authorization-with-users-in-a-database