# Is it possible to tie authentication directly to specific XHTML files in JSF2?

Tags: authentication, jsf-2

I know that I can restrict page access in `web.xml` using `<security-constraint>`, or that I could write custom phase listeners or web filters that would check the auth status for each request.

What bugs me about these approaches is that I am defining which resources are off-bounds in a different place than the resources themselves, i.e. I have to remember to update the URL patterns of my filters or the web.xml when I create or move JSF's xhtml files.

**What I would like to have is something similar to an annotation directly on the file.**

I've seen people use the `<f:preRenderView ...>` tag in their xhtml files, which comes very close, but I feel that that's way too late in the JSF lifecycle.

What options do I have?

Or is this not advisable at all?

Comment: Not advisable at all.

Comment: @BalusC keeping it short and sweet. I'm guessing your advice would be to use a ``@WebFilter``? I think I've seen you mention that elsewhere.

Comment: Several ways. http://stackoverflow.com/q/9965708